# Error serializing - using getServerSideProps in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

An error showing

> Error: Error serializing `.myBlogs` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/blog".```

while I am trying to console data! While I was fetching data through `useEffect()` everything was going well, but now fetching data with `getServerSideProps` it throws error mentioned above!

**Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/Blog.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'

const blog = (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  const [blogs, setblogs] = useState([]);
  // useEffect(() => {
  
   
  // }, [])
  return <div>
    <Navbar />
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h2 className={styles.heading}>
        Latest Blogs :)
        {/* Get started by editing{' '}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.js</code> */}
      </h2>
      <div className={styles.neat}>
        {blogs.map((blogitem) => {
          return <div className={styles.grid} key={blogitem.slug} >
            <Link href={`/blogpost/${blogitem.slug}`} >
              <a className={styles.card}>
                <h2>{blogitem.title} &rarr;</h2>
                <p>{blogitem.content.substr(0, 100)}...</p>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>

    </main>
  </div>

}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blogs');
  let myBlogs = await data.json();

  return {
    props: {myBlogs}, // will be passed to the page component as myBlogs
  }
}

export default blog
```

Comment: `let myBlogs = data.json();` ... `myBlogs` will be a promise, since that is what `.json()` returns  ... you'll need to `await data.json()`

Answer (score 0):

As @Bravo suggested, you should `await` the `data.json()` call in the `getServerSideProps` callback.
Also, you should destructure the `props` object to receive the `blogs` loaded and display them.
Finally, it is good practice in `React` to capitalize component names:

```
const Blog = ({ blogs }) => {
  return <div>
    <Navbar />
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h2 className={styles.heading}>
        Latest Blogs :)
        {/* Get started by editing{' '}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.js</code> */}
      </h2>
      <div className={styles.neat}>
        {blogs.map((blogitem) => {
          return <div className={styles.grid} key={blogitem.slug} >
            <Link href={`/blogpost/${blogitem.slug}`} >
              <a className={styles.card}>
                <h2>{blogitem.title} &rarr;</h2>
                <p>{blogitem.content.substr(0, 100)}...</p>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>

    </main>
  </div>

}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  let data = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blogs');
  let myBlogs = await data.json();

  return {
    props: { blogs: myBlogs }, 
  }
}

export default Blog
```