# blogs.map is not a function error in next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-development-server

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const Home = (props) => {
  const [blogs, setblogs] = useState(props.data);

  return <div className={styles.container}>
    <Head>
      <title>BlogsWap</title>
      <meta name="description" content="New App" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>

    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>
        Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">BlogsWap!</a>
      </h1>

      <p className={styles.description}>
        An all time blog for coders!
      </p>
      {blogs.map((blogitem) => {
        return <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>{blogitem.title} &rarr;</h2>
            <p>{blogitem.content}</p>
          </a>

        </div>
      })}

    </main>

    <footer className={styles.footer}>
      <a
        href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        &copy; BlogsWap
        <span className={styles.logo}>
        </span>
      </a>
    </footer>
  </div>

}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let totalBlogs = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blogs');
  // console.log(totalBlogs)
  let data = await totalBlogs.json();
  return {
    props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}

export default Home
```

I am getting error like:

`TypeError: blogs.map is not a function`

What should I do? I have no idea why it appeared because,
recently I have used similar method but it all was fine
now it throwing such error!
Please help me in to get the error out!

Here is the photo of the error :(

[Photo of the error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Hiv.png)

Comment: Please show what console.log(data) says

Comment: It shows the same which photo I attached in question!

Comment: I mean the value in this : let data = await totalBlogs.json();

Comment: It is all okay. it gets the json data!

Comment: But is it in correct format is the question. That is why I am asking

Comment: Please show us what `console.log(data)` returns inside `getServerSideProps`. We know `data` is defined, otherwise you'd get a different error, but it's most likely not returning an array, which means it doesn't have the `.map` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `getServerSideProps` like this, return something meaningful which actually represents your data, not a keyword like data, it's confusing.
By returning `{ props: { blogData } }`, the component will receive `blogData` as a prop.

```
  let blogData = await totalBlogs.json();
  return {
    props: { blogData }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
```

Then you need to change the input of component where you are passing props, it's now `blogData`. Notice the change here, destructuring is being used here.

```
const Home = ({ blogData }) => 
const [blogs, setblogs] = useState(blogData);
```

Finally in the jsx also do null check to safely access object

```
 {blogs && ....
   <map goes here>
 }
```

Or

```
 {blogs ? 
    <map goes here>
    :
    else show a loader here
```

Also I hope `blogData` is an array type, if not convert it to array using

```
Array.from(blogData)
```

because `.map` only works on array.

Comment: Nothing happened!

Comment: @GodCoderz - Then pls check what you are getting from service, `blogData` . I doubt it''s not array but object. Because looking at the screenshot of image you posted it's only possible if your data is not array. Put console.log after await and see what is it

Comment: Yeah! It is an object!

Comment: What should I do now then?

Comment: You have to transform the object to array, how to do it, impossible to say without seeing the data.

Comment: Not actually because I have did this project recently and I have used same method here is the code of that project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198728/error-serializing-using-getserversideprops-in-next-js

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accessing blogs, you need to pass blogs as a key:

```
 let blogs = await totalBlogs.json();
 return {
    props: { data : { blogs } }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
```

Or you can do this:

```
const [blogs, setblogs] = useState(props);
```

Comment: No actually, it doesn't work!

Comment: I am surprised by your solution that how can you pass ```{data : { blogs} }, ``` when it is not defined in ```getServerSideProps()```

Comment: My bad, had to use the variable above there.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the `blogs` object is undefined and thus, `blogs.map` is also undefined, raising an error when being called.

Try using optional chaining:

```
{blogs?.map((blogitem) => {
...
```